# Lazy loading in windows phone 8.1

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, lazy-loading, c#-5.0

Is there any article or sample for windows phone 8.1 Lazy loading without any third party toolkit I had gone through google and haven't found any working or sample or article which can help me to implement Lazy loading in windows phone 8.1.

Comment: Your question is way too general for anyone to help you with. Lazy loading is simply accomplished by not initializing something until you need to use it. There's a variety of ways, like lazy loading singletons to accomplish it. Please be more specific about your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can incrementally load `ListView`'s items in Windows Phone 8.1 without using any toolkit if you simply take out the `ScrollViewer` of the `ListView` and subscribe to its `viewChanged` event handler to check the scroll progress. If the progress is more than a certain threshold then call the function to fetch more items. 
Use this function to get the scroll viewer.

```
public static ScrollViewer GetScrollViewer(DependencyObject depObj)
{
    if (depObj is ScrollViewer) return depObj as ScrollViewer;

    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);

        var result = GetScrollViewer(child);
        if (result != null) return result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here's a step by step tutorial on its implementing lazy loading in WP 8.1 WinRT app without using any toolkit. 
http://www.windowsapptutorials.com/windows-phone-8-1/listview/lazy-loading-listview/